# Query only Document objects using Data Model in SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, data-model

I can query the objects through SOAP API for the list of objects. But I  require only the Document, Note and Attachment objects. How can I query the objects using the [describeSObjectResult](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) call?

The data model is described [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_erd_recordtype.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_erd_recordtype.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Comment: are you trying to retrieve metadata for document, note and attachments? or are you trying to retrieve their records?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve its records. I get the list of all the objects but I need to query only the Document, Note and Attachment objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, the following code should help.

```
Map<String, SObjectType> objMap =  Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        SObjectType type = objMap.get('snoteandattachment'); // sdocument for Document
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult typeDetails = type.getDescribe(); 
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap =  typeDetails.fields.getMap(); // to get a map of all the fields from DescribeSObjectResult object.
```

Comment: Thanks. The above code is using Apex if I'm not wrong. Can this be done similar through soap/rest API?

Comment: Yes, I did one Rest call to get the list of Available SObjects. Just send a request to 
`/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/`

Comment: I get that for list of objects. Schema.getGlobalDescribe() is not available in SOAP/REST. The REST call returned the DescribeSObjectResult object. I guess this is not possible without using Apex.

Comment: What exactly do you want in response from Salesforce? If you want to describe an object, use - `/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/describe`. Replace Account with your object api. 

Refer to this [blog](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-rest-api-playground/), it has pretty good example of Rest calls to Sf.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use direct queries via SOAP API to retrieve records for these objects for e.g

**Document**
select id, name from Document

**Attachment**
select id, name from Attachment

**Note**
select id, body from Note

Comment: That sounds good for this case. For example, if the user says that I have to query only the support objects, per [this] (https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_erd_recordtype.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_erd_recordtype.htm|SkinName=webhelp) my idea was to 1) get the list of all the objects, 2) find the object type (category), 3) Query the objects selected in step 2. Is this the only option through SOAP API?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to identify objects dynamically, then you would probably need to first fetch all available objects and then progress to query records of selected objects. This can be achieve through SOAP/ REST api.

Comment: I need a more robust case for identifying as mentioned above . That's the solution in Apex. I require a solution in Java using SOAP/REST. Through the calls, the only information that I can extract about the type of the objects is Standard/Custom. I do not know what the object type is.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what do you mean by "determining object type"?

Comment: My objective is to query objects with a customer mentioning the [predefined types](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm). The user mentions that query the 'sales object' only and my job has to query all the objects that has been mentioned [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm). My flow is to query using SOAP API using DescribeSObject call and there is a method isStandard()/isCustom() to identify whether the standard or custom object.

Comment: Well, there is no way to identify Sales or Service objects via API unless you maintain a categorization of objects yourself. You can store names of all Sales objects in your application and fire describe calls to get their metadata information. Further, once you have metadata, you can dynamically form queries, to fetch records